# TypeTag and comparison operators?

Tags: scala, reflection

I don't really understand why you can't work with a `TypeTag` object itself, can someone explain why the below code doesn't work? I'm also asking why the `TypeTag` object doesn't directly support operators like `=:=` . I know this has something to do with the `typeOf[T]` function, but frustratingly I can't seem to grab this directly either (example `myTT.typeOf`)

Thanks

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object TestRun extends App {

  class Matcher[T:TypeTag] {
    def test[U](x: U)(implicit tag: TypeTag[U]) = {
      val myTT = implicitly[TypeTag[T]]

      println("=:=" + myTT =:= tag) //error
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `tpe` method:

```
println("=:=" + (myTT.tpe =:= tag.tpe))
```

(You also need another set of parentheses because of the left-associativity of `+`)

Comment: Thanks, do you have any insights about how the tpe object differs from the TypeTag itself? I don't understand what the point is of the typetag class if we just immediately work with tpe